# How to make the words in pictures from Mathematica into MS Word can be edited?

Tags: graphics, export, interoperability

I find that when I export graphics to PDF format from *Mathematica*, the words in pictures can be copied. However, when I save the pictures from *Mathematica* and then insert those pictures into MS Word, the words in pictures can't be copied. If I want to place the pictures from *Mathematica* in MS Word and have the words in pictures copyable, how shall I do?

```
Plot[{x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include a minimal working example to make your question more concrete. This way you can get focused replies.  A minimal example includes enough code that respondents can copy-paste to their notebooks to replicate the problem locally. Thanks.

Comment: Your title suggests you want to change the text but if fact you just wan't to select it and copy it to the clipboard. Correct?

Comment: @Syed Thanks. I have made change on my question.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino I just want to select it and copy it to the clipboard.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino I have to use MS Word to make a file in which I will need to insert several graphics from Mathematica. After I transfer Word to Pdf, I find the words on pictures in Pdf can't be selected and copied. How shall I do if the words could be copied?

Comment: There is a relatively new (and maybe limited) feature in MS Word that will import an SVG file (which can be exported from *Mathematica*).  After importing the SVG file into MS Word, right-click on the graphic and choose "Convert to Shape".  That converts every little thing to a separate object.  For example, the text "1.0" becomes 3 graphics objects and replacing text is not readily apparent.  Maybe you'll have more luck than I have had with it.

Comment: @JimB This way works well in MS Word. But transfer Word to Pdf, the text of picture can still not be copied or edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way (as far as I know) to edit a vector image in MS Word is to use one of the Microsoft's Vector Graphics Formats: `.WMF` or `.EMF`.

You can export graphics from Mathematica in either of those formats, however, they have been [deprecated](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/WMF.html) from version 12.3 on.

If you have an earlier version of Mathematica, you can try doing this:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]
Export["test.wmf", %]
```

and importing the image in MS Word. You should be able to right-click on it, and then Edit Image will allow you to change the text.

Comment: I am using a version 13.0. I right click the picture in Mathematica and select **Save As**, then I can't find the .WMF or .EMF choice. May you tell me how to export graphics as .WMF or .EMF?

Comment: @Y.zeng You need an older version of *Mathematica* for exporting to these formats (lower than version 12.3, where they [replaced the legacy GDI-based rendering with modern DirectWrite-based](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2431430)).

Comment: @Y.zeng Earlier you could use EPS format for obtaining vector figures in MS Word, but MS seemingly [dropped](https://superuser.com/a/1631563/71768) support for this format in the latest versions.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Okay. I will use latex instead of MS Word.